# How to route internet traffic through Google

Tags: proxy, google, tor, internet

I'm in a situation where my network provider blocks all my internet access except for Google and its branches (Drive, Gmail, etc).

I'm looking for a way to route my traffic through Google (with Google proxy or VPN or Tor bridge, etc) to be able to full access internet.

Is such thing possible and, if it is, how?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/ssh-tunnel-on-gce

Comment: you can't do all traffic, but sheet's http api could be used to grab external domain content and pull it into the google domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into [domain fronting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_fronting). Unfortunately, it seems that Google has disabled support for this just last month (April of 2018), preventing Tor's [meek](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/meek) pluggable transport from using it to evade authoritarian censorship. If there are any other web services which you are able to use for domain fronting, you may want to use them instead. If that doesn't work at all, you can visit arbitrary web pages by using Google Cache or Google Translate as a make-shift web proxy.

As [Steffen Ullrich](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/37315/steffen-ullrich) mentioned in a comment, you can also run a proxy or VPN on [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/compute/), assuming the IP addresses associated with it are not blocked. There are also a number of free, public CGI web proxies scattered around the internet that run on a Google service.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Fi](https://support.google.com/fi/answer/9040000?hl=en) users and [Google One](https://support.google.com/googleone/answer/7582172?hl=en&ref_topic=7576171) users are entitled to use a Google-run VPN on their Android devices, over both Wi-Fi and cellular data. Caveats:

- They are both paid services. In the US, Google One costs a [minimum](https://one.google.com/about/plans) of $10 per month or $100 per year* and Google Fi costs a [minimum](https://fi.google.com/about/plans/) of $20 per month.**
- As far as I have been able to determine, Google Fi and Google One are only available to US residents. However, Google Fi does support international roaming to a [large number of countries](https://fi.google.com/about/international-rates/) at no additional cost.
- The Google Fi help page explicitly indicates that tethered data is not handled by the VPN. I suspect the same is also true of the Google One VPN. So don't expect to extend this to your non-Android devices.

Disclaimer: I work for Google. This is not a sponsored or official answer. My knowledge of these services is limited to the publically-available help documents (see links above).

---

* Cheaper plans exist, but they don't include the VPN.
** Price for one person; multi-person plans are cheaper per person. Price does not include data, but you can use the VPN over Wi-Fi.